# Como alterar cor de um Text de uma ListView?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-berlin

Preciso que meu ListView identifique os valores de um item Text, por exemplo:  , "Completo"/"Pendente" e faça com que cada um tenha uma cor diferente dentro da ListView. Tentei formatar por código, mas não consegui, vi que na .VCL tem o CustomDrawSubItem que coloca-se o loop lá e faz isso, porém não achei no .FMX que é o que eu quero. A que tem abaixo dá Acess Violation, como devo fazer isso?

```
procedure TformExames.listView1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);

var
  i : integer;
begin 

  for i := 0 to listView1.Items.Count -1 do

    if listView1.Items[i].Text = 'Cancel' then
    listView1.BeginUpdate;
    listView1.Items[i].Objects.TextObject.TextColor := 444444;
    listView1.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filipe,

Existe uma forma de alterar as propriedades de cada componente de texto (ou qualquer outro) dentro de um listview. Para isso, você faz um loop em seu list view e para cada item da lista, procura o(s) texto(s) correspondente e altera as propriedades que desejar.

No exemplo abaixo, imagine que tenha dois componentes de texto no item da listview e deseja alterar as cores apenas do text com name "MeuBtn". você faria da seguinte forma:

```
uses FMX.ListView.Types;

var
  i : integer;
  txt : TListItemText;
begin 

listView1.BeginUpdate;

for i := 0 to listView1.Items.Count -1 do
begin
    txt := TListItemText(listView1.Items[i].Objects.FindDrawable('MeuBtn'));

    if txt <> nil then
    begin
        txt.TextColor := $FF434A52;
        txt.Font.Size := 13;
        ...
    end;    
end;

listView1.EndUpdate;

end;
```

Espero ter ajudado! ;)

Comment: Fiz o que você falou, dá o seguinte erro: [dcc32 Error] frmExames.pas(70): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TListItemText' and 'TListItemDrawable'

Comment: Dentro do for, substitua o "txt := ..." por: txt := TListItemText(listView1.Items[i].Objects.FindDrawable('MeuBtn'));

Comment: Agora sim, isso que eu queria. Grato!

Answer (score 1):

Vou te passar como resolver, tive o mesmo problema com a cor, o **FMX** trabalha com `TAlphaColor`, com isso ele não entende se colocarmos uma cor por exemplo: `clRed` ele tem as cores pré-definidas:

Se você quiser usar uma determinada cor, teria que fazer da seguinte forma:

```
ListView1.Items[i].Objects.TextObject.TextColor := TAlphaColorRec.Green
```

Todas as cores pré-definidas, estão em **TAlphaColorRec**, agora se você quiser uma cor personalizada. Você deve desenvolve uma função.

```
function ColorToAlphaColor(Value: TColor): TAlphaColor;
var
  oCRec: TColorRec;
  oARec: TAlphaColorRec;
begin
  oCRec.Color := Value;
  oARec.A := 255;
  oARec.B := oCRec.B;
  oARec.G := oCRec.G;
  oARec.R := oCRec.R;
  Result  := oARec.Color;
end;
```

Para a cor que você escolheu começar a funcionar no FMX, você deve fazer o seguinte:

```
ListView1.Items[i].Objects.TextObject.TextColor := ColorToAlphaColor(StringToColor('$0080FFFF'));
```

Com isso o FMX vai assumir a cor que foi determinada.

Answer (score 0):

```html
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  ListView1.BeginUpdate;
  for i := 0 to ListView1.ItemCount - 1 do
  begin
    if ListView1.Items[i].Text.Equals('Pendente') then
      ListView1.Items[i].Objects.TextObject.TextColor := TAlphaColorRec.Red
    else
      ListView1.Items[i].Objects.TextObject.TextColor :=
        TAlphaColorRec.Yellow;
  end;
  ListView1.EndUpdate;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  item: TListViewItem;
begin
  item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  item.Text := 'Pendente';
  item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  item.Text := 'Completo';
  item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  item.Text := 'Pendente';
  item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  item.Text := 'Cancelado';
end;
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou certinho!

Comment: Tive apenas agora uma problema, pois mudei para DynamicAppearence e incluir novos componentes Text. Nomeei eles como atributos do meu Binding e tento colocar ListView1.Items[i].(nomedoatributo).Equals('Pendente') then e não funciona. Não sei como acessar os itens em particular.